# best practice to check NVR status using upnp or http

Tags: http, protocols

I have a huge number of NVR devices for video surveillance let's assume it will be 20k distributed in different geographical locations, each one of them has it is own static IP.

I need to check It's status every 3 second for example,  should I use http requests? I also found something about unpn protocol for device discovery ?

what is the best practice to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are talking about NVR devices, simple ping or http connect shouldn't suffice, since I've seen many cases where NVR/DVR returned ping, http port was open, but the device itself was broken.

So, the way to do this would be:

1. Dependent on the manufacturers and the SDK they provide, you can use that SDK to connect and disconnect to and from the device using device login information, since that would be the only way to know for sure that the device is alive.
2. If the device support alarm center function, you could use that option to setup the device to connect to your software you in case something is wrong with the device (hdd fail, camera fail, etc...). You could implement a timer in your application and implement first method to periodically test the "health" of the device. So, if the login returns true, you are ok, if not, generate a message in your software or do whatever you think is right. Of course, this also implies that you are using vendor provided SDK which provides this callback possibility.

Also, 3 seconds I think it's a bit over the head, so I would recommend extending that period.